# Example to clarify fill_value when using add() on dataframes (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm learning pandas these days. I have a rudimentary question regarding the `fill_value` parameter when using `add()` on dataframes.

Imagine I have the following data:

`dframe1`:

`A   B
NYC 0   1
LA  2   3`

`dframe2`:

`A   D   C
NYC 0   1   2
SF  3   4   5
LA  6   7   8`

Doing `dframe1.add(dframe2,fill_value=0)` yields:

`A   B   C   D
LA  8.0 3.0 8.0 7.0
NYC 0.0 1.0 2.0 1.0
SF  3.0 NaN 5.0 4.0`

Why do I get `NaN` for column `B`, index `SF`?

I was expecting that `fill_value` ensures no results of `NaN` occur by - in this case - assuming column `D`,`C` and index `SF` exist with value `0` for `dframe1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html

Probably this is the case of:

Fill missing (NaN) values with this value. **If both DataFrame locations are missing, the result will be missing.**

I bet you already know the `fillna` for pandas:

```
df.fillna('', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation